# Are the "VPN" Chrome extensions really a VPN or a web proxy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vpn

A client is asking me if I could create a "VPN" extension that can connect to their VPN server. I have seen numerous VPN extensions on the Chrome Web Store, but they only affected Chrome. Doesn't a VPN affect *all* connections?

I have found `chrome.proxy`. Are the VPN extensions really VPN's or are they actually web proxies? Can I tell the client that they need to setup a web proxy server instead of a VPN server, and I use `chrome.proxy` for this purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many "VPN" extensions are essentially proxies, indeed: they cannot affect anything except the traffic of the browser itself (through `chrome.proxy` and `chrome.webRequest` API).

There are, however, two exceptions.

1. On Chrome OS (and Chrome OS only) an extension can use [`chrome.vpnProvider` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/vpnProvider) to broker a connection to a VPN.
2. Using [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), you can have an extension communicate with another application running in the OS that can manage "true" VPN connections. However, that does require a separate installation of such a module with appropriate OS permissions, and makes the Chrome extension nothing more than a remote control for it.

So using the path #2 above, it is possible to create a *true* VPN extension, but that would require software installation outside of the browser.

Comment: Do you know any vpn services that use chrome.vpnProvider ?